# How do I view Sricam QZT IP camera on MacOs Sierra

Tags: macos-sierra

I have a MacBook Air running Sierra. I have a Sricam Indoor IP Camera Model SP020. I can view the image on my iPhone 6 through a Sricam App, but they have no software for Mac laptops.

How can I view my camera's image on my laptop?

Comment: Short answer: You can't. Apparently Sricam thinks it's a good idea to use proprietary protocols so you can only view it using proprietary software that runs in Windows, Android or iOS only.

Answer (score 0):

Since the SP020 [supports ONVIF](http://www.sricam.com/product/id/5a51c5577e3a4950a81a0edc416aad26.html) you can try to search for such apps that run on OSX.

[IP Camera Viewer 2](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ip-camera-viewer-2/id595565459?mt=12) and [SecuritySpy](https://www.bensoftware.com/securityspy/) for example. At least two apps I tested a while ago with a friend. Probably some more osx ip cam apps out there supporting onvif.

Comment: I have downloaded IP Camera Viewer, but it comes without any instructions, such as how to connect the camera. Do you know of a source?